# Email sending failed

Tags: email, smtpmail

I send emails with <kbd>C-x m</kbd> and AFAIK everything is configured
OK. However, recently I got this response when I wanted to send an email:

> smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:
>   Connection lost to authentication server in response to AUTH PLAIN <long
>   hash here>

My second attempt resulted in (from `*Messages*`):

> Sending via mail...
>   Sending email
>   Sending email done
>   Sending...done

Now I have two questions:

1. Why did it fail the first time?
2. Can I be sure that my email has been sent after all?

---

Update: through experiments I've discovered the following:

1. This happens when title of email is written using Cyrillic script;
2. Email is delivered anyway on second attempt.

Seems it's sort of bug, but I will wait for additional clarification.

Comment: And you are sending emails with what library . . . Wanderlust, mu4e, View Mail, R2D2, C3PO?

Comment: @lawlist, how can I check it?

Comment: If nothing special is known, chance are that it is just stock gnu:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sending-Mail.html#Sending-Mail and http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusTutorial

Comment: @lawlist, I guess so, since it seemed to work I never bothered to switch / dig into this.

Comment: Can you an example of text that is failing?

Comment: @IqbalAnsari, what do you mean exactly, title of email or error message? I think I've posted the error message already.

Comment: I meant title of the mail

Comment: @IqbalAnsari, "Заголовок на русском языке" does the trick for me. Maybe other non-latin characters (Greek for example) produce the same effect, but I haven't tried.